# Used SSH to establish internal connection to another virtual machine; now I can't change it back

Tags: ssh, samba, hosts

I logged onto my server from a remote computer via SSH using its hostname `server.domain.com`. The Samba server's IP is `192.168.5.33`.

I then used the ssh command to connect with the local FTP server (192.168.5.37): `ssh 192.168.5.37`. Got asked if I want to proceed as the fingerprint was not in the list of known hosts. Confirmed, and it got permanently added to the list of known hosts.

Whenever I connect to `server.domain.com` now, I end up on `192.168.5.37` instead of `192.168.5.33`. If I use `ssh 192.168.5.33`, I end up in a main directory containing the files `initiatorname.iscsi  iscsid.conf  nodes` instead of what I expected in the root directory.

How do I get back to the root where I will find folders like `/var/logs`?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect via ssh you enter the remote machine in the home directory of the user you are using to connect `/home/username` (or `/root` if you are connecting as root, but this is not permited by default on ubuntu for security reasons).

If your `ssh server.domain.com` command sends you to the ftp server instead of the 192.168.5.33 machine, you have a routing problem or a DNS problem.

Your router (or firewall, not sure how is your configuration) can be redirecting port 22 to ftp server or you DNS resolver (local `/etc/hosts` file or DNS server or Samba server if you are using it to resolve hostnames) is pointing to your ftp server IP for host server.domain.com.

Look at the output of `nslookup server.domain.com` on your machine to verify if this is a DNS related problem.

Obs: not sure if you need that, but to go to the `/` directory (where you find `/var/log`) you need to issue `cd /` command. SSH connections will never leave you there by default.

---

**edit after comment**

Ye, from nslookup output, it is your name resolution (done on server 192.168.5.33) that is sending you to the wrong server.

Look at your `/etc/hosts` files in both servers and correct if wrong:

On `192.168.5.33`, you should have the line

```
192.168.5.33 server.domain.com server
```

and on the ftp server, you should have:

```
192.168.5.37 ftpservername.domain.com ftpservername
```

Check the names of the servers with `hostname` on each and correct with `hostname correctname` and edit the config file with `nano /etc/hostname`.

Not sure how is DNS resolved on your network but if you are using bind, you will need to correct its zones config files too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Your hint with the `cd /` command helped me a lot.

Comment: I just tried `nslookup`, and the result is:

`Server:         192.168.5.33`
`Address:        192.168.5.33#53`
`                           ` 
`Name:   server.domain.com`
`Address: 192.168.5.37`

What does it tell me? I still end up on 192.168.5.37 everytime I connect to server.domain.com. And from the `nslookup` output it seems to be meant like this, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, it is meant like this by a wrong dns resolution. I edited the answer.